# My Subscribe to mailing list only works with logged in users

Tags: profile, groups

I've made a Profile that allows me to add someone to a mailing list from a html snippet.

But only users that are logged into civicrm can finish the form, when you attempt to submit i get this error: "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.
The requested Profile (gid=13) is disabled OR it is not configured to be used for 'Profile' listings in its Settings OR there is no Profile with that ID OR you do not have permission to access this profile. Please contact the site administrator if you need assistance."

The form asks for;
First name
Last name
Email
Mailing list to be added to.

I have set everything  i think i need to to public page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some permissions with profiles and you have to set those permissions for the anonnymous user. Those permissions are calles profile listsing.

If you are using Drupal you could try to create a webform with the webform and civicrm integration.

Comment: Thankyou, i forgot to let anonymous users create profiles in a moment of derpyness.